# How do I tell my supervisor that I've been offered a job and want to leave?

Tags: advisor, quitting

Yesterday I posted about wanting to leave my PhD and I've definitely decided that it's the healthiest choice for me. Now comes the hardest part- telling them that I plan to leave the program once I find an alternative role. I'm not a very confrontational person and I hate to feel that I am wasting anyone's time so I want to be as polite and direct as I can be.

Is it as simple as emailing to say that I wish to discuss my progress and long term goals and then inform them during the meeting that I've been offered a job?

Comment: *Now comes the hardest part- telling them that I plan to leave the program once I find an alternative role.* have you or have you not got an offer?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-'s question is important. If you desire to leave and have not yet secured another position, you should say nothing. However if you do already have something lined up Buffy 's answer is good.

Comment: Nobody wants to supervise a student who wants to be somewhere else. Even if there's a little disappointment on their part, telling your supervisor will be doing them a favor—you're letting them know that you're taking steps to make a better situation for you and a situation for them where they can direct their energy elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

There is no reason for it to be confrontational. It is a sad situation, not a confrontational one. Just say that you are leaving and have considered your options.

Don't get talked out of what you want to do. If the person is angry, that is on them, not you. Say you are sorry, but determined.

Make some effort to clean up unfinished work that impacts on others if that is at all possible.

Comment: To the user who raised Low Quality Post flag, would you please explain the reason to raise the flag? I fail to see what's wrong with this answer.